# Basically I have this question about triangle meridians in my Geometry class.

Tags: geometry

There is an image of a triangle with 3 meridians across it. There is no information about the sides' lengths. I have to find the lengths of meridian AM and meridian ME using a linear equation. The problem is that last year was virtual and I didn't learn much. I have to find x and also find the answers to the questions asked. All I need to know right now is how to solve that algebraic equation: ME = 5x-6 and AM = 7x+3 Here is a picture.

[image]

Comment: By meridian, do you mean [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry)), or is it another kind of [cevian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cevian)?

Answer (score 1):

You need the fact that the centroid of a triangle (the point $M$ in your diagram) divides the median into $2/3$ and $1/3$ of its length.  So $ME$ is $1/3$ of the length of $AE$.   So you have to solve the equation

$$2(5x-6) = 7x+3$$

because $AM$ is twice the length of $ME.$